# How to get one value from a set of fields while having multiple buttons?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am looking for help with passing ajax jquery value.
I want to pass one value only  from  a php while loop. There are multiples buttons and I get only the first value. It is like adding friends in facebook. You have a list of button and when you click the button you get the exact clicked value. 
My problem is that I get the first value.
Thank you.

```php
while(){
  echo ' <form>
       <input type="hidden" name="f_'.$name.'"  id="f_'.$name.'" class="f"     value="'.$name .'" /> ; 
    <input type="button" name="add_friend"  class="ajax_add_friend "  value=" friend "   />
    </form>';
}
```

```js
$('.ajax_add_friend').click(function() {
    var f = $(".f").val();
    var msgbox = $(".f_status");
    if(f.length > 6 ) {
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "parse_file.php",  
            data: "f="+ f , 
            //data:   yourArray ,
            cache: false,
            success: function(msg){
                $(".f_status").html(msg);
                if(msg ) { 
                    msgbox.html(msg);
                }else{  
                    msgbox.html(msg);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you add the code to your question, please?

Comment: when you assign f do `$(this).prev('.f').val();` should give you the one you are looking for.

Comment: Try to change var f = $(".f").val(); with var f = $(this).val();

Answer (score 0):

What you do there:

```js
var f = $(".f").val();
```

Will give you the value of the *first element in the document* matching the selection pattern `.f` and that is your first text input field.

Instead you should locate your text input field to get the value from *relative to the clicked button*.

This leads to a pattern like this:

```js
var f = $(this).parent().find(".f").val();
```

Or this:

```js
var f = $(this).prevAll(".f").val();
```

[Edit]

Or this:

```js
var f = $(this).parents("form").find(".f").val();
```

Comment: @Gham If thats the case, you whithheld some important information. See [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KcFg3/).